# Need single code to work on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms

I am creating a gallery by scraping a folder of images, each image also has a dropdown. I can get the code to work for a single split value dropdown, but when i add the code to my image array, it only pulls the first selection and is not splitting the value correctly on submit. How do I make it work on multiple image/dropdowns?

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<select name="location" id="location">
<option value = '' selected> None </option>
<option value = 'bsimage1:folder1'> folder1 </option>
<option value = 'bsimage2:folder2'> folder2 </option>
<option value = 'bsimage3:folder3'> folder3 </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
onclick='brochure_select()' value="Submit">
<input type="hidden" id="fid" name="fid" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="sid" name="sid" value="" />
<script>
function brochure_select() {
    var option_result = document.getElementById("location").value;
    var option_array=option_result.split(":");
     document.getElementById('fid').value = option_array[0];
    document.getElementById('sid').value = option_array[1];
}
</script>
<div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $fid = $_POST['fid'];
        $sid = $_POST['sid'];   
        echo "You have selected : " .$fid. " to move to " .$sid; // Displaying Selected Value
print_r($_POST);        
};
?>
</div>
```

here is a sample of what the multiple selector currently looks like: this code scraps the folder for images and outputs them into a gallery on a page, I have added a dropdown select to each image, but it is not passing the value chosen for each image into the form correctly.  here is a url eaxmple.
http://mangamike.com/demo/index-split.php

```
  <?php 
// Image extensions
        $image_extensions = array("png","jpg","jpeg","gif");

        // Target directory
        $dir = 'images/';
        if (is_dir($dir)){

            if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
                $count = 1;

                // Read files
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

                    if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                        // Image path
                        $image_path = "images/".$file;
                        $image_ext = pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                        // Check its not folder and it is image file
                        if(!is_dir($image_path) && 

                            in_array($image_ext,$image_extensions)){
                            ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                            <!-- Image -->
                            <a href="<?php echo $image_path; ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" alt="" title="" height="auto" width="auto" style="max-width:350px;min-height:250px;"/>
                            </a>
                            <!-- --- -->
                            <div style="float:left;padding:5px;">

                             <div class="form-group">           
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Brightsign Image Name - <strong><?php echo $file; ?></strong></label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="location" name="location[]" >
                                        <option selected disabled value="">Choose Location</option>
                                        <option value="closing">Closing Station</option>
                                        <option value="device">Device/ROF</option>
                                        <option value="merch1">General Merch 1</option>
                                        <option value="merch2">General Merch 2</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="image_name[]" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
                        </div>          
                        </div>
                        </div>
                            <?php

                            // Break
                            if( $count%3 == 0){
                            ?>
    </div><div class="row">
                            <?php    
                            }
                            $count++;
                        }
                    }

                }
                closedir($dh);
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, or the code. Would you mind explaining the problem differently, or name the files you're showing. Does the first code block (with the form) submit to the second code block (test2.php)?

Comment: no the second block shows how I am trying to implement the first block, the second block outputs as many divs as there are images in the folder that is being scraped, it also duplicates the dropdown, but i am having an issue where the dropdown values, when submitted do not get passed correctly through the JS and PHP

Answer (score 0):

1. javascript isn't updating your hidden inputs before the form is submitted
2. the hidden inputs aren't in a form

Maybe have two forms, where the first form@onsubmit you preventDefault pull the data out that you want, shove it in the other form and submit that one.